# OUTFILE MySQL not working with union

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT t1.email FROM(
SELECT email, SIGN(Locked1) FROM table WHERE SIGN(Locked1) <> 1
UNION
SELECT email, SIGN(Locked2) FROM table WHERE SIGN(Locked2) <> 1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT email, SIGN(Locked3) FROM table WHERE SIGN(Locked3) <> 1
)t1
INTO OUTFILE 'emailDump.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

This query runs but nothing is put into the outfile. If I run the query without the last line, the rows do show up so it is not because the unions do not produce a result. I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: `If I run the query without the last line`...can you post another sample without that line??

Comment: SELECT t1.email FROM(
SELECT email, SIGN(Locked1) FROM table WHERE SIGN(Locked1) <> 1
UNION
SELECT email, SIGN(Locked2) FROM table WHERE SIGN(Locked2) <> 1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT email, SIGN(Locked3) FROM table WHERE SIGN(Locked3) <> 1
)t1

Answer (score 0):

It may be the location. The following syntax is correct. We will put it in the root of C:.

```
SELECT email
FROM table 
WHERE 
SIGN(Locked1) <> 1 or
SIGN(Locked2) <> 1 or 
SIGN(Locked3) <> 1
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\emailDump.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

Comment: Same issue with this syntax.

Comment: are the tables the same table?

Comment: If they are the same table, then you don't need to perform a union - see my edit.

Comment: I would think you would need OR instead of AND in your where clause.

Comment: The new syntax also returns an empty file

Comment: @user2924127 I have changed the AND to OR - can you try it again?

Comment: The OR also returns empty

Comment: I think it is the location of emailDump.csv - can you try the latest edit

Comment: Same issue. By the way I had to use 'C:/emailDump.csv' instead of 'C:\emailDump.csv'

Comment: @Donal - yes they are the same tables

Comment: just for fun -  If I just go Select * FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'C:/emailDump.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"; it does work, but this is not the result I need.

Comment: What does this do: SELECT email
FROM table 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\emailDump.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";

Comment: This also outputs data

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

This is probably a permissions issue.  The expression:

```
INTO OUTFILE 'emailDump.csv' . . .
```

Is putting the `.csv` file in whatever the current directory is.  That is probably some special directory for MySQL and the user may or may not have access to it.

I would suggest putting in a complete path where you know you have write permissions.  As a bonus, you'll later be able to find the file if you want to use it for some purpose.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I tried 'C:\emailDump.csv' and other locations, but the same issue persists.

Comment: @user2924127 . . . Try a directory where you know you have permissions.  Can you create a file in `c:\`?

Comment: @user2924127 . . . Does the filename already exist?  MySQL doesn't overwrite files.

Comment: Yes I can. The syntax creates a file in that directory, but it is just empty. If I just run -- select * from table INTO OUTFILE 'C:\emailDump.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"; --  then it works. Also I make sure to delete the files before and if I don't, I get an error telling me the file already exists, so I don't think that is the issue.